# linux cron not calling jar file in shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, sh

I am trying to run jar file using the shell script. While manually running shell script it is working perfectly. If i ran through `cron` it is not running. The below is my command inside `run.sh`

```
/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java -cp "/lib/*" com.abc.def.Main;
```

The all jar files are inside the lib directory.

I redirected the `cron` output to log file, it is not printing any logs in the log file. The below is my `cron`.

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/run.sh >> /test.log 2>&1
```

If i put some echo statements in the `run.sh` it is redirected to the test.log file otherwise nothing it prints in the log file.

Kindly tell me what is the mistake i am doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of time, when something runs in shell but not in cron, it is because you have something in your environment that cron does not know about.  Remember that cron runs a sh shell, without loading your environment.  What you can do: log at the java level (ex. log4j), check the cron logs, check your email (cron will email output), load your environment configuration as the first step in your cron script (ex. `. /home/user/.bashrc`).

Comment: See also the troubleshooting section in the [Stack Overflow `cron` tag wiki](/tags/cron/info)

Comment: A lot of what you are doing is looking like it requires root access, while the `crontab` entry looks like a regular user's entry. Please [edit] the question to clarify how this is not a permissions problem.

Comment: Found issue log file is not loaded, due to calling the script in cron it is setting /root as home directory from /root it cant able to find the log file. I used resourceasStream method to load log file, it is searching from /root instead of class path location.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path for /lib/*
(like /home/user/lib)